# Add text replacement programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, replace, keyboard

In iOS there is this nice feature to add text replacements, for example if you type "idk" it automatically replaces it with "I don't know" if you added this specific replacement under settings - General - Keyboard -  Text Replacement. So I would like to integrate this feature into my app, so I can add Text Replacements from within my app. Is that possible and if yes, how can I access it? Hope you guys got what I mean and hopefully it's possible! Thanks for any help and sample code :) 
Btw, I'm programming in swift.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a specific API available for this (maybe something called text expansion or replacement related to UITextField) but you could create your own relatively easily.

You can interact with the text being typed via the delegate object for a text field and check for certain things and change the string as needed while the user is typing in it.

> A text field manages the editing of its text with the help of its delegate object. As the user interacts with a text field, the text field notifies its delegate and gives it a chance to control what is happening. You can use the delegate methods to prevent the user from starting or stopping the editing process or to validate text as it is typed. You can also use the delegate methods to perform related tasks, such as updating other parts of your interface based on the information typed by the user.

[UITextField Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/)

And there is additional information about the [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006991).

[Here](http://rshankar.com/textfieldshouldreturn-uitextfielddelegate-method-in-swift/) is a small example doing something with the UITextFieldDelegate that you should be able to expand to what you'd like.  You might even be able to find sample code that does more or less what you're looking for if you search for 'UITextFieldDelegate text expansion example' or something like that.

Hope that helps some.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I think the problem is that the user should be able to use those replacements in other apps too, not just inside my own app. That's why it would be great to create this "original" Apple replacement inside the system settings.

Comment: @beginner_T did you figure out a way to do that? I'm looking for the same.